# d3 stack area data format issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a stack area chart using d3 but all the examples i saw have different data format then mine and i am not able to figure out how to draw the chart using my data format.

For example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685

Here is my data:

```
var data = [{data: [
["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]],
label: "a"}, {data: [
["2016-01-20T05:31:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:31:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:32:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:32:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:33:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:33:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:34:17.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:34:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:35:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:35:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:36:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:36:47.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:37:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:37:47.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:38:17.000Z", 95.4, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:38:47.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:39:17.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:39:47.000Z", 96.1, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:40:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:40:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:41:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:41:47.000Z", 94.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:42:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:42:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:43:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:43:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:44:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:44:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:45:17.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:45:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:46:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:46:47.000Z", 96.0, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:47:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:47:47.000Z", 96.2, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:48:17.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:48:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:49:17.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:49:47.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:50:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:50:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:51:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:51:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:52:18.000Z", 95.5, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:52:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:53:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:53:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:54:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:54:48.000Z", 95.9, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:55:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:55:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:56:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:56:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:57:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:57:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:58:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:58:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:59:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T05:59:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:00:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:00:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:01:18.000Z", 95.6, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:01:48.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:02:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:02:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:03:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:03:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:04:18.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:04:48.000Z", 95.8, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:05:18.000Z", 95.7, {}],
["2016-01-20T06:05:48.000Z", 95.7, {}]],
label: "b"}]
```

So please help me in creating a stack area chart using my data format.

Comment: What is the required format?

Comment: @MarkChorley: I edited the question. Can you suggest me how to create a stack area graph using my data format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataset is already in the formatted form so you will not need the nested function as in the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685)

However you will need to merge all the arrays to get the max and min out of it.

```
var ary = [];
layers.forEach(function(d) {
  ary.push(d.data);//collecting all data
})

x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return new Date(d[0]);
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(ary), function(d) {
  return d.y0 + d.y;
})]);
```

Rest is as in the example.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KZtiM7Zdr77BP2EePRQL?p=preview)